# Why is the absolute integrability criterion "inverted" for local integrability with respect to improper integrability?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory

In the context of Riemann integrals, I've noticed that for improper integrability:

(1) $|f|$ is improperly  integrable $\implies f $ is improperly integrable

but when it comes to local integrability it is the other way around

(2) $f$ is locally integrable $\implies |f| $ is locally integrable

**Why is that? what's wrong about the following proof:?**

If $|f|$ is locally integrable
$|\int_a^b{f}|< \int_a^b{|f|}<+\infty $   $\implies f$  is locally  integrable

Can't this prove that (2)'s converse is true, that is that if $|f|$ is locally integrable $\implies f $ is locally integrable? I know however it can't be since as a counterexample if $g $ is the Dirichlet function , $|g|$ is locally integrable but $g $is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converse to (2) is only true if you're talking about Lebesgue integration since measurability is invariant across taking absolute values. You're not completely correct in that the Dirichlet function, say $g$, would satisfy that $|g|$ is locally integrable, since $g=|g|$ as the Dirichlet function only takes positive values. If you define something like
$$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\
-1 & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q},
\end{cases}$$
then $\varphi$ would give you the desired property in terms of local integrability. Further, regarding your concerns about relationship of (2) to (1), the hypothesis in (1) is actually: if $f$ is locally integrable, then $|f|$ is improper integrable implies $f$ is improper integrable, with the counterexample of the converse being $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. If you want to see a proof of why $\varphi$ is not locally integrable, let me know.

Proof of $\varphi$ not being locally integrable:

Let $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we can compute $U(\varphi)=1$ and $L(\varphi)=-1$ because no matter how you partition the interval $[a,b]$, each sub-interval will have a rational point and an irrational point. Thus, for all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$, we must have $U(f;P)=1$ and $L(f,P)=-1$. Then, by the definition of upper and lower Riemann sums, we have $\varphi$ is not Riemann integrable (this is the same proof as why Dirichlet function is not Riemann integrable).

Comment: Thanks, I confused the Dirichlet function,the one you are showing is what I had in mind. Why is my proof of the converse of (2) wrong?

Comment: Because to show a function is locally integrable, you need to show that the upper and lower Riemann sums are equal to each other on any interval (I assume that's your definition of local integrability). It doesn't make sense to write $\int f$ without this condition. Again, a function can only be improper integrable if it is local integrable and satisfies the condition that its local integrals converge when taking a limit on its bounds.

Comment: @mathlover i.e. when you write $|\int_a^b f|\leq \int_a^b |f|$, you are assuming that the upper and lower sums of $f$ are equal to each other, which is not the case for the function I specified in my answer.

Comment: Could you add that proof of why $\phi$ is not locally integrable?

Comment: and maybe that of sin(x)/x for the improper integrability as well

Comment: @mathlover see my new edits. For the proof that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is improper integrable, use integration by parts and take the limit of each side to infinity (you may need to split the integral into 2 to do this)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116534/discussion-between-varpi-and-mathlover).